# Java Output Code of Simple Calculator is not worked output correctly?

Tags: java

The Code is to simply display calculations of two numbers taken from user

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class simple_Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input First Number:");
        int num=in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Input Second Number:");
        int num1=in.nextInt();

        int a,b,c,d;
        float e;
        a=num+num1;
        b=num-num1;
        c=num*num1;
        e=num/num1;
        d=num%num1;

        System.out.println("num"+"+"+"num2"+"="+a);

        System.out.println("num"+"-"+"num1"+"="+b);

        System.out.println("num"+"*"+"num1"+"="+c);

        System.out.println("num"+"/"+"num1"+"="+e);

        System.out.println("num"+"mod"+"num1"+"="+d);


    }

}
```

[Look it is not correct of divide and modulus whats the problem can you help me to fix this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGPvW.png)

Comment: U divide integers. Convert em to float first.

Comment: can you send code which is error and where should i debug

Comment: oh..........................

Answer (score 0):

When diving `int`s you lose accuracy. You should cast each operand to `float` or simply use `float`s in  these operations. This is the way you can cast both operands to `float`:

```
float e = (float)sum1/(float)sum2;
```

Answer (score 0):

With a Type Cast your code should work correct.

```
e = (float)num / (float)num1;
d = (int) ((float)num % (float)num1);
```

http://www.studytonight.com/java/type-casting-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Integers will simply truncate numbers after decimal point. It cannot be a decimal value and the division you are doing is of two `int`, so it simply discards the value after decimal point. Try this,

```
float x1 = (float)num;
float y1 = (float)num1;
float e = x1/y1;
```